# Does Network Device Management VLAN Need To be On An Access Port Or Can It Travel In A Trunk?

Tags: switch, vlan, management

SO I am building a network of 6 switches. 1 primary switch would feed a trunk of 4 VLANs to 5 other switches directly (i.e. all coming from the primary switch). To keep the switches secure I want to put them on their own Management VLAN. If I am  going from one switch to another to carry my initial 4 VLANs can I TAG the 5th VLAN for network management to travel on the same trunk? And also when the trunk port meets the destination VLAN would you still be able to access the switch directly through the trunk port or would would you need a second ACCESS line connection the two switches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A management VLAN is the same as any other VLAN, so yes, you can include it on your trunk ports.  Just make sure the management interface is in the correct VLAN.

Comment: Going a step further. I currently have this setup as everything on VLAN 1. But I can't access the management pages from 1 switch to the other. I can't even ping them. BUT I can ping computers connected to those switches. Is that weird? They are ALL on VLAN 1.

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting, you will need to edit your question to include the switch configurations.  A simple diagram would help too.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to include management Vlan on trunk link . So that futher it will be easy for network admin to access -switch from any Vlans connected host by simple  access list configuration allowing management Vlan and network admin host connected Vlan .